# Append results of parsed tuple to a similarly named external lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I am parsinging a URL, extracting tags and values.  I created a list of all the tags and am trying to append the values to the appropriate list.  There's a sample URL below, it contains three 'utm' tags, utm_source, utm_medium, utm_campaign.  The tuple (x,y) has the tag name and value.

My problem is in the last line.  I want to 'append' the value (y), to the LIST of the same name as the tag (x), is that possible?  Should I be creating dictionary within a dictionary? TIA.  Eli

===========================================================================

```
utm_source = []
utm_medium = []
utm_campaign = []

url = 'https://www.focus.de/politik/ausland/weltkriegs-entschaedigungen-ziehen-in-die-schlacht-polen-und-griechen-kaempfen-nun-gemeinsam-um-reparationen_id_11122350.html?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=facebook-focus-online&fbc=facebook-focus-online&ts=201909091311&cid=09092019&fbclid=IwAR3R6tPi3TvS11j5ZzC_UCRMxgaY2Op6UDBKa5jKPIm4ZAhaErLMMY4WaqE'
terms = re.findall("(utm_.+?)\&", url)
print(terms)

for t in range(len(terms)):
    try:
        x,y = terms[t].split('=')
    except:
        x = 'excep'
    x.append(y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store them properly by pair, yes a dictionary is good way, also you can directly iterate over the terms

```
d = {}
for term in terms:
    try:
        x, y = term.split('=')
    except:
        x, y = 'excep', None
    d[x] = y
```

Using dict comprehension style

```
d = {k: v for k, v in [term.split('=') for term in terms]}
```